# A good way to proceed to Hartshorne.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I am going to take a course in Algebraic Geometry covering chapter II and III of Hartshorne next year. Before this, I have the option to take either Commutative Algebra (Mainly use Atiyah) or Riemann Surface & Algebraic Curves (Mainly Rick Miranda) next semester.

As I know, commutative algebra provides the necessary algebraic tools to handle algebraic geometry. Some said it can be learnt along Hartshorne while some said it is better to learn commutative algebra before learning Hartshorne.

Also, some mentioned Riemann Surface & Algebraic Curves (over $\mathbb{C}$) provides geometrical intuition as they are the prototype to modern algebraic geometry which helps in understanding the concept in Hartshorne.

Which is **more important** for me to move into Chapter II and III of Hartshorne? I wish to pick both but unfortunately, I am overload next semester so I can only pick one.

*By the way, I had taken a course in algebraic curves where lecture note by William Fulton was used. Thus, I know a bit commutative algebra from there but not as much as in Atiyahs'*

Comment: You mean Atiyah-Macdonald? I wouldn't suggest doing those simultaneously, no. Commutative algebra first is probably a good idea to get a good feel for ideals, quotient rings, notherianness, localisations, dimension theory and more before venturing out into the geometry side of things.

Comment: @Arthur . Yes, it was the book by Atiyah-MacDonald. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: If you have already taken a course in algebraic curves _and understood it well_, then it seems redundant to take a course in Riemann surfaces. On the other hand, if you didn't gain much intuition for algebraic curves despite taking the course then it might be a good idea to try a different perspective.

Comment: As currently worded, this is a request for personal advice and [off-topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @KReiser It can be useful when people in the community want to choose what to study before Hartshorne.

Answer (score 2):

To understand chapters II-III of Hartshorne you *need* much of the material in Atiyah-Macdonald. The material in Miranda's book will help a lot with the motivation, however while the definitions and results in Hartshorne may sometimes resemble those in Miranda's book, the arguments will almost always be done using commutative algebra. As such, to understand Hartshorne you should take commutative algebra.

Ideally, of course, you would take both classes. However, since you already had a course in algebraic curves it shouldn't be a serious issue to not take the course on complex curves.

Comment: I'm going to disagree that you "*need*" the material of Atiyah-Macdonald. Hartshorne's honestly not so bad at introducing the appropriate results from commutative algebra as he needs them, and the bits and pieces of commutative algebra that do come up don't appear so quickly as to overwhelm you. As long as one has seen some basic operations with rings and modules (quotients, localizations, etc) which should be covered in any abstract algebra course, I don't think it's completely necessary to go through a whole commutative algebra course.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. It is true, however, that the material in the first 3 chapters of A-M equips one very well for understanding a large portion of Hartshorne.

Comment: If only 3 chapters of A-M is needed, perhaps I can study myself during my summer break and take Riemann surface instead? (In fact, I learnt module in my abstract algebra course, but not about localization. )

Comment: I think localization is absolutely mandatory. If you are comfortable with basic commutative ring theory, localization, tensor products, etc. you should be fine. You will eventually need to return to A-M to learn the rest of the material, though. In particular the material on valuation rings is very important (actually I need to learn it more deeply).